# Pointer syntax query

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I can't seem to understand the difference between the following to pointer notations, can someone please guide me?

```
 typedef struct some_struct struct_name;
  struct_name this;
  char buf[50];
  this = *((some_struct *)(buf));
```

Now I tried to play around a bit and did the above thing like:

```
  struct some_struct * this;
     char buf[50];
     this=(struct some_struct *)buf;
```

As far as I am concerned I think both the implementations should generate the same result, Can someone guide me whether there is a difference between the two and if yes can some one point it out?

Thanks.

Comment: Get out of the habit of using "this" as a variable name RIGHT NOW.  If you're doing C now, you're going to be doing C++ some day, and you're going to regret that habit.

Comment: @PaulTomblin: C and C++ are different languages.  I don't think using "this" as a variable name in C is that big a deal.

Comment: @ Paul Tomblin Thanks for the advice, I actually just wanted to clear things so unintentionally wrote this as a variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first snippet, `this` is not a pointer, it's an instance of `some_struct`. The assignment you made did a shallow copy (i.e. `memcpy()`) of what's in buf as if it were an instance of `some_struct` as well.

In the second snippet, `this` is a pointer, and it's just pointed to the address of `buf`.

So, basically to sum up, first snippet `this` is not a pointer and the struct is copied into it. In the second, it's a pointer and assigned to the same memory as `buf` (i.e. not a copy).

Comment: Thanks alot, that explains it :)

Comment: @Abdullah, you are a bit too fast. This answer is correct (and I gave it my +1) but it doesn't tell you the hidden problems that your code has. Please see my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the second one, "this" will point to the first memory location of "buf". In the first example, you will either get a compiler error (I don't think you can assign structs in C with =, I could be wrong though), or the contents of buf (up to sizeof(struct_name)) will be copied into this, which resides on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches have their problems.

- alignment: your `buf` might not be properly aligned for a variable of the structure type. If so this will produce undefined behavior (UB): in the best case it aborts your program, but it may make much worse things than that.
- initialization: in the first cases you access uninitialized memory for reading. In the best case that gives you unspecific data, that is some random bytes. In the worst case, `char` is a signed integer type on your platform and you hit a trap representation for `char` => UB as above. (Your second case will encounter the same problem, once you try to access the object at the other end of the pointer.)

How to avoid all that:

- *Always* initialize your variables. A simple `= { 0 }` should do in all cases.
- never use `char` as a generic type for bytes but use `unsigned char`
- never cast a byte buffer of arbitrary alignment to another data type. If needed, do it the other way round, cast a `struct` object to `unsigned char`.

Comment: Thanks alot Jens, I will try to avoid such mistakes in future, cheers :)